# Put 'Blanks' into Row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this

```
A      B
0abc   3
1c     4
```

and I want to query like this putting blanks 10 times;

```
A        
0abc          3
1c            4
```

This is just an example, this could be 100 blanks too. Which function should i use ?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to query like this putting blanks 6 times`?

Comment: @PankajGadge Putting blank means is ' ' -->

Comment: `'      '||A` use concatenation `||`

Comment: It's still not clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example should be:

```
with sqf
  as (select --+ choose
             '0abc'       "A",
             3            "B"
        from dual
       where 1e1 = 1e1
       union all
      select --+ choose
             '1c'         "A",
             4            "B"
        from dual
       where 1e1 = 1e1
     )
select --+ choose
       rpad(s.a, 10) || to_char(s.b)   "PADDED_LINE"
  from sqf  s
 where 1e1 = 1e1;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions107.htm#SQLRF00663

Comment: Thank you. However now i understand that my needs are lil different. Edited my question.

Comment: `--+ choose`? Wasn't that a hint once, back in 9i?